# JPA spring boot insert into child table based on condition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one to many relationships in parent and child but I want to insert in the child based on condition only but parent table always.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement can you please add more information and an example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you provide more details what you trying to or you can can share what u did yet

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful if you could provide us the data structure with example records like:

table 1
column1 | column 2 | column 3
value   | value    | value

table 2
column1 | column 2 | column 3
value   | value    | value